# IndexError: list index out of range when using a table exported from mathematica

Tags: python, matplotlib, wolfram-mathematica

I have a problem when trying to plot some data, using Matplotlib, with a text file obtained from Mathematica-Wolfram.
The code is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.artist as pltart


params = {'font.size': 11,
'axes.labelsize' : 18, 'axes.titlesize' : 18,
'xtick.labelsize' : 18, 'ytick.labelsize' : 18,
'figure.figsize' : [6.0,4.4],
'figure.subplot.left' : 0.13, 'figure.subplot.right' : 0.999,
'figure.subplot.bottom' : 0.16, 'figure.subplot.top' : 0.999}

plt.rcParams.update(params)

x=np.arange(7,24,0.1)

M3=0.47e-3*x**3

plt.figure()

RhoS,MS,RS,=np.loadtxt('Static.pnr',usecols=(0,1,2),unpack=True)

# MtotVsRtot plot

plt.plot(RS,MS,'k-',color='red',linewidth=2.0)

plt.plot(x,M3,'k-.',color='grey',linewidth=1.5)

plt.xlabel(r'$R_{\rm eq}\,(\rm km)$',fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel(r'$M/M_{\odot}$', fontsize=20)

#plt.show()
plt.savefig('MvsR_L&P_GM1.eps')
#exit()
```

The text file is obtained from mathematica with the command:

```
Static = Table[{KepSeq[[i, 1]], 
 KepSeq[[i, 2]], KepSeq[[i, 3]]}, {i, 1, 
 Length[KepSeq]}] // TableForm

Export["Static", Static, "Table"]
```

where `KepSeq[[i,j]]` is just a matrix of values.

It appears that, even if Mathematica correctly generates a three columns text file, Matplotlib is not able to recognize such columns, indeed, using a text file builded by hand for test, I get no problems.

Using a .txt file do not solve the error, of course.

The error, as from title is: `IndexError: list index out of range.`

EDIT:

> aside just do Static=KepSeq[[All, 1;;3]]. Have you studied the file to be sure it is all numeric?

I noticed that the table created by mathematica is composed only by numbers. BUT, "copying and pasting" it on a empty .txt file, shows a lot of hidden characters, as paranthesis, commas and other:

```
\!\(\*
TagBox[GridBox[{
{"19.30736436824425`", "0.49704178850444225`"},
```

...

```
{"11.327870685578393`", "2.199907624212163`"}
},
GridBoxAlignment->{
     "Columns" -> {{Left}}, "ColumnsIndexed" -> {}, 
      "Rows" -> {{Baseline}}, "RowsIndexed" -> {}},
GridBoxSpacings->{"Columns" -> {
Offset[0.27999999999999997`], {
Offset[2.0999999999999996`]}, 
Offset[0.27999999999999997`]}, "ColumnsIndexed" -> {}, "Rows" -> {
Offset[0.2], {
Offset[0.4]}, 
Offset[0.2]}, "RowsIndexed" -> {}}],
Function[BoxForm`e$, 
TableForm[BoxForm`e$]]]\)
```

Any idea on how to get rid of it? In the meanwhile, the (clearly unsatisfactory) solution has been copy and past and then delete by hand the extra-characters.

Comment: aside just do `Static=KepSeq[[All, 1;;3]]`.  Have you studied the file to be sure it is all numeric?

Comment: looking again, you are assigning `Static` to the `TableForm` formatted expression. Get rid of `TableForm` should fix things.  (completely pointless to follow `TableForm` with a semi colon anyway, it says "format this nicely but don't show it"..)

Comment: precisely, as I said get rid of `TableForm`, or if you want to see it too do this: `(Static=KepSeq[[All, 1;;3]])//TableForm`  Note the parenthesis which cause `Static` to be assigned the numbers before formatting.

Comment: Yep, sorry I still have to completely understand how to edit and answer. Anyway I edited the main text trying to answer to your doubt.

Comment: also, stick with your original `Export`, not copy-paste.

Comment: Ok, I understood the problem. The table was including a first line made by alphanumeric characters with the function of "names" of any columns. Then I was commenting it, in the .txt file, with `#` to make it readble by python. But, in this way, mathematica was wrongly exporting the hidden extra-characters. Just creating the table starting form the second line... `{i, 2, Length[KepSeq]}]` ...solved the problem. @agentp